# How to get javascript `this` element properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been learning javascript to get clear of the jquery that's why I'm gonna show you an example with jquery and how to write same code with js

I have to do list like this:

```js
var addText = document.querySelector("#addText"),
  addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");


addText.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (addText.value.trim().length > 0) {
    addButton.removeAttribute("disabled", false)
  } else {
    addButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  }
});

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var textVal = addText.value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = textVal + " - <span class='removeTodo' onclick='removeTodo()'>Remove</span>";
  ul.appendChild(li);
  addText.value = '';
  addText.focus();
  addButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
});
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function removeTodo(event) {
  //
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="" id="addText">
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" disabled>
</body>

</html>
```

and as you see on snippet I have removeTodo() function.. I want to remove `li` which I clicked but before do this I have to ask how can I get clicked properties (id,class,text,parent,child bla bla) and how can I remove or addClass (for example) ?

it was very simple with jquery like this

```js
$(element).on("click", function() {

  $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).text();
  $(this).remove();
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parents().attr("class");
})
```

Comment: Some equivalents are: `this.id`, `this.textContent`, `this.parentElement.removeChild(this)`, `this.style.display = 'none'`, and the last one needs a bit more effort. Check https://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Comment: Also, `onclick='removeTodo()'` should be `onclick='removeTodo(this)'`. Also consider adding the click event in JS rather than as an attribute.

Comment: @MichaelGeary you seem to have missed the point - the OP is using those jQuery methods as an example of how he wants to access the element that raised the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the method you're using - where you expect the event to be passed as an argument to the function - you can use `event.target` to access the clicked element. Note that you will need to amend the `onclick` to include the `event` in the arguments, though.

However, a much better solution would be to use an unobtrusive event handler on the `li` as you are on all the other elements in your code. Then you can use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element, similar to the jQuery example in your second code block. Try this:

```js
var addText = document.querySelector("#addText"),
  addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");

addText.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  addButton.disabled = addText.value.trim().length == 0;
});

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var textVal = addText.value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = textVal + ' - <span class="removeTodo">Remove</span>';
  li.addEventListener('click', removeTodo);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  addText.value = '';
  addText.focus();
  addButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
});

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function removeTodo() {
  // read properties here...
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
  
  // then remove the element...
  this.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="addText">
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" disabled>
```

Comment: Clicking the whole `li` removes it.

Comment: In which case you can call `remove()` after reading the required properties. I updated the answer to show exactly how.

Comment: Hi Rory Mcrossan thank you so much for sample..I wrote as your code but in my document remove is not working ? http://jsbin.com/yocijaneda/edit?js,console,output

Comment: That's because you're still using the outdated `onclick` attribute. Remove that and use the unobtrusive `addEventListener` as in my example above

Comment: I see and it was what I looking for thank you so much Rory I'm appreciative you

Comment: Hi again I've another question with trim method when I press the space trim function is not work addButton is not disable again ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. It would be best to start a new question about it, with a clear description of the issue and your code.

Comment: I mean this area `addButton.removeAttribute("disabled", addText.value.trim().length == 0);` is not control space value/empty value for example space button

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That was my mistake. I updated that line of code in the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Your event object is going to have an `event.target` field that will hold the DOM object you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is not the best practice. You should for example add another element for `span`, `addEventListner` on it and append `span` to your `li`.

```js
    var addText = document.querySelector("#addText"),
      addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");


    addText.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      if (addText.value.trim().length > 0) {
        addButton.removeAttribute("disabled", false)
      } else {
        addButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
      }
    });

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

      var textVal = addText.value;
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = textVal + ' - ';
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.innerText = 'Remove';
      span.className = 'removeTodo' 
      li.appendChild(span)
      ul.appendChild(li);
      span.addEventListener('click', removeTodo);
      
      
      addText.value = '';
      addText.focus();
      addButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(ul);

    function removeTodo(event) {
      console.log (event.target) // this is a span
      console.log (event.target.parentElement) // this is a li
      event.target.parentElement.remove(); // remove li
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="" id="addText">
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" disabled>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code in an answer. It doesn't help to educate the OP or future visitors at all.

Comment: Please tell us what changes you made, and how you got the OP's request to work.

Comment: there is something you wrong I don't want to do this with jquery I just want to do pure javascript I'm trying to learn :)